# IE9 not recognizing font-weight: lighter

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, font-face, google-webfonts

Look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vkNtK/1/

In IE9 those two h2's render the same, and in all other modern browsers the first one uses the light version of the font. Does anyone have a solution to force IE to use the lighter font when font-weight:lighter; is declared?

To be clear: we're talking about IE9, why isn't this working in IE9?

Comment: You could always use `300` or `400` and specify the font weights explicitly.

Comment: IE has supported `@font-face` since IE 4.

Comment: @Blender - No I can't, tried that long before posting the question, no effect within my project or within the JSFiddle illustrating the problem.

Comment: @Jukka - true, now that you say that I do remember using some font-face in older IE's. Guess it's just been so long since I worried about whether fonts looked good in IE8 that I forgot :) I'm editing the question to remove that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with this specific font, or with the way Google makes IE use it. Your code works for other Google fonts with Book (300) font weight, like Lato and Open Sans.

Comment: Have no idea why someone downvoted this, it may not solve the problem, but it gives huge insight into why it exists. And it's absolutely true (just tested it myself). I'm upvoting it just to bring it back to zero :)

Comment: In fact, I've now tested about a bazillion google fonts (I counted...that's the real number...) and all of them work fine, just Oswald doesn't. So I'm gonna officially say that the problem itself is not solvable because there is something about the actual font file for the 300 weight font that IE won't recognize. So I'll award you as the correct answer.

I'll also add that just leaving IE to render the 400 weight while the rest do the 300 isn't a good option, because the 300 renders about 20px lower than the 400, so it requires different layout CSS. Conclusion: don't use Oswald 300.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a new font-family name for the light fontface and targeting specific elements.  I only use this font-name in CSS for IE.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontname-light';
  src: url('../webfonts/EOT/fontname-light.eot');
  src: url('../webfonts/EOT/fontname-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../webfonts/WOFF/fontname-light.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../webfonts/TrueType/fontname-light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
}
```